# Use MPMoviePlayerViewController interface on device while movie on big screen

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, media

I want to implement external screen suppor for my iOS app and want to use the standard playback interface of the MPMoviePlayerViewController, i.e. use this 'good' slider with 50, 25% scrubbing and so on...

So far, I tried the following: present the mpmovieplayerviewcontroller with the right movie and then just add the controller.moviePlayer.view to the external screen window, but it results in a black screen on the tv after 1/2 second video...

Is there any possibility how I can use the standard controls on the phone while playing on the external screen?

Thanks in advance,
Christian